# .trc file error log(table not found)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

> > My application use oracle as a database in production. Seens few days it is creating lot of .TRC file.When I am checking for the log  it was (Table Not Found). But all my transaction run properly Without any problem.
> >
> > As per my investigation If table is not their then there should not be transaction success. Still I am not able to reach in the real resign for the Error(Issue).
> >      As I am new to this error   Any suggestion or solution will help me out.

Comment: Doesn't the trace file say which table, or at least which query was being executed at the time?

Comment: @AlexPoole it is just showing Table or view Dose not exist.An  it is creating lot of .trc file usually i never get that. Can you guess what will be issue.

Comment: There is no table name or query. i am only getting the error"Table or view Dose not exist".As it is a batch job i can't getting which part of the query it is giving error. i need the idea what will be the possible cases.